# somepage.azurewebsites.net page can’t be found deployment ASP.NET Core 7 Web API

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, .net-7.0

I know that question is rather amateur but I hope someone will give me a hint what I did it wrong.

I'm using:

- Azure SQL Server database - I can access it from Azure db instance from my local SSMS
- Azure App Service - also created, up and running

VS22 deployment => Publish => connect to my Azure account, and imported publish profile.

Deployment went well: and the code in release mode is published to Azure App Service.

But I can't see my Swagger page on my Azure website.

I'm using .NET 7

Maybe you can tell me what I'm missing here? Maybe I need to wait for instance of azure app service to be created? although I can access it and use all features that I paid.

Also, my logs are empty

Comment: Is this are you ask for GoTo App service-->API-->API Management-->click on the APPwhich you have added ? In this way you will get Swagger page of App like [this](https://i.imgur.com/ZhPUgyG.png)

Comment: To rule things out: is the app.UseSwagger / app.UseSwaggerUI inside the `Environment.IsDevelopment()` if? If so: remove it from the if or add `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`: `Development` to you App Service configuration. Do the last thing only during development and remove it before launching to production.

Comment: @Michel This worked but I also had to navigate to /swagger/index.html. Adding this incase someone else comes across this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample webapp in visual studio 2022 using .net 7

Image for reference:

[image]

I connected to my Azure sql database from SSMS to the webapp using visual studio.
Image for reference:

[image]

It connected successfully. I published it to Azure through Visual studio 2022.
For that I created an app service in azure.
Image for reference:

[image]

published into that APP.
Image for reference:

[image]

It published successfully.
Image for reference:

[image]

It run successfully after deployment.
In portal I go to API-->Api management and created new api for my app.
Image for reference:

[image]

[image]

I linked the Api Management and click on the Api which I created I got the swagger page
Image for reference:

[image]

In this way we can find the swagger page for an App in azure portal.